Bitbucket/Firebase-deploy upload returned 400
I am migrating CI from appcenter to bibucket and firebase.
The build is okay, but I am getting error on deploying the file to Firebase.
Here's the error
INFO: Executing the pipe...
INFO: Starting deployment of the project to Firebase.
✖ Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.

For my pipeline
image: node

...

name: Build and Deploy Android APK
deployment: development
image: reactnativecommunity/react-native-android
size: 2x
caches:
  - gradle
  - node
script:
  - yarn 
  - npx pod-install
  - echo "$JKS_FILE" | base64 -d > android-signing-keystore.jks
  - cd android
  - chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew clean
  - chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew assembleRelease
  - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:0.2.1
    variables:
      KEY_FILE: $JKS_FILE
      FIREBASE_TOKEN: $FIREBASE_TOKEN
      PROJECT_ID: $FIREBASE_PROJECT
artifacts:
  - build/**

then for my bitbucket variables
I have these
JKS_FILE
SIGNING_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS
SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD
FIREBASE_TOKEN
FIREBASE_PROJECT

Is there anything wrong or missing?

The error message "HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument." usually occurs during the onboarding process of your app to Firebase App Distribution. Make sure you click the “Get started” button in the App Distribution console before uploading your app.
Also, check your configuration file if the appId matches your app in Firebase. You can find the appId by following the steps below:

Navigate to Project settings
Select your app
Check the App ID value on the right side

